# Allow domain with a point in a cloud page by using html

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, cloudpage, landing-page

I'm creating a formular in html so as to integrate it in a cloud page on marketing cloud.
I ask for an email address. I want to allow email address with a "." in the domain, for example : test@my.domain.com

My code for the moment :

```
<div class="srf-field_wrapper">
                    <label for="emailAddress">E-mail*</label>
                    <input id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" required="" type="text" placeholder="Ex: mon.adresse@email.fr*" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]+" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Veuillez remplir ce champ obligatoire')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                </div>
```

Does someone know how to adapt my code so as to allow this kind of emails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your regex to allow for that extra 'dot' in the domain, like this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\.[a-z]+
```

You can check how this behaves in my regex example here: https://regex101.com/r/EqJzPg/1

Comment: thank you a lot